# Scaling RatingBar doesn't remove the frame around it

Tags: java, android, view, ratingbar

I want to use the Android `RatingBar`. Works great on Tablets but on smaller screens the rating bar is huge. I read that I should use the `ScaleX/ScaleY` functions and it works also great. However, it shrinks the rating stars but keeps the object wit a bigger frame.

See this example, I colored the `TableRow` in green (which wrap the content) and the `RatingBar` in blue 
[image]

You can see that the actual stars shrink, but the frame of the original size stayed the same.

Here is an example with EditText box. I did the same thing to make sure the issue is with the RatingBar. In this image you can see that TableRow wrap the Text perfectly. (no green background)
[image]

My goal is to shrink the frame of the RatingBar to the blue frame.